# What is the difference between "+" and "," when printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between these two pieces of code?

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello " + name)
```

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello ", name)
```

I'm sorry if this question seems stupid; I've tried looking on Google but couldn't find an answer that quite answered my question.

Comment: When you tried it, did you *see* a difference?

Comment: Please update your question with the google results you found that didn't quite work for you.

Comment: how many spaces are there between each output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, you have to add an extra whitespace after Hello.

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello " + name)
```

In this example, you don't have to add an extra whitespace (remove it). Python automatically adds a whitespace when you use comma here.

```
name = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello ", name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('a'+'b')
```

Result: ab

The above code performs string concatenation. No space!

```
print('a','b')
```

Result: a b

The above code combines strings for output. By separating strings by comma,  print() will output each string separated by a space by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)`
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*.

The default separator between `*objects` (the arguments) is a space.

For string concatenation, strings act like a list of characters. Adding two lists together just puts the second list after the first list.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` function definiton is here: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#print)

```py
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)
```

Better to explain everything via code

```py
    name = "json singh"

    # All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does 
    # and written to the stream, separated by sep (which is ' ' by default) 
    # These are separated as two separated inputs joined by `sep` 
    print("Hello", name)
    # Output: Hello json singh 

    # When `sep` is specified like below
    print("Hello", name , sep=',')
    # Output: Hello,json singh
```

```py
    # However the function below evaluates the output before printing it
    print("Hello" + name)
    # Output: Hellojson singh

    # Which is similar to:
    output = "Hello" + name 
    print(output)
    # Output: Hellojson singh

    # Bonus: it'll evaluate the input so the result will be 5
    print(2 + 3)
    # Output: 5
```